# UWP - How to apply CharacterSpacing to PlaceholderText

Tags: textbox, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to know that is there any way to apply CharacterSpacing to PlaceholderText in TextBox?

I tried to edit TextBox template and I noticed a ContentPresenter is showing PlaceholderText, I tried to use CharacterSpacing on it, but it did not work. Also, I tried FontStretch and again no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to edit TextBox template and I noticed a ContentPresenter is showing PlaceholderText, I tried to use CharacterSpacing on it, but it did not work

The `PlaceholderText` is presented inside a [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) for the when use [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx). And `PlaseholderText` is the value of [`content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.content) property. The type of  `content` property is `object`, in the meanwhile, `CharaterSpacing` property is an attribute for string. So it seems like this is the reason why `CharaterSpacing` doesn't take effects. You will find controls  with `Text` property such as `TextBox`,`AutoSuggestBox` and `TextBlock` can take effects on `CharaterSpacing` property  since the type of [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.text) property is `string`.

> How to apply CharacterSpacing to PlaceholderText

If you want to apply `CharaterSpacing` to `PlaceholderText` here, you can use `TextBox` control instead of the `ContentControl` for `PlaceholderTextContentPresenter` to be a new style which will not influence the `PlaceholderText` feature. But you need to do some changes for appearence to let it seems same with before. Update code for the new `TextBox` style as follows:

```
  <TextBox
      x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
      Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
      Foreground="Gray"
      CharacterSpacing="1000"
      IsHitTestVisible="False"
      BorderThickness="0"
      Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" />
```

And the result:

[image]